# Get max url from PostgreSQL statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, greatest-n-per-group

I have a very complex query which generates a view in PostgreSQL. 
Now the query returns duplicated rows, well almost duplicated: one field, the "url" column is different.

Now we still want to group those "almost duplicated" rows. We can do this by skipping the `url` column, but we need that column. We already got the latest date by using this statement:

```
max("cdata".date) AS date
```

So we would like to do the same thing, but with `url`. So get the latest row by `date` and show that url.

Is this possible?

Like I said, the query is complex, so creating a subquery which executes the same query again with some changes wouldn't be a good idea. Also I don't have a primary key, so that makes it even more difficult. I hope you guys have some kind of idea to fix this issue.

The current query:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cdataview AS 
 SELECT md5(ROW("cdata".acc_id, "cdata".adgcid, "cdata".adgid, "cdata".kid, "cdata".sterm, "cdata".mtype)::text) AS id,
    "cdata".acc_id,
    "cdata".kword,
    "cdata".kid,
    "cdata".url,
    "cdata".adgcid,
    "cdata".adgname,
    "cdata".adgid,
    "cdata".adgstatus,
    "cdata".sterm,
    "cdata".mtype,
    sum("cdata".cost) AS total_cost,
    sum("cdata".cval) AS cval,
    sum("cdata".impr) AS impr,
    sum("cdata".clicks) AS clicks,
    sum("cdata".convcl) AS convcl,
    ( SELECT accs.name
           FROM accs
          WHERE accs.id = "cdata".acc_id) AS accname,
    ( SELECT cmps.name
           FROM cmps
          WHERE cmps.id = "cdata".adgcid) AS campname,
    ( SELECT kpr.qscore
           FROM kpr
          WHERE kpr.id = "cdata".kid
          ORDER BY kpr.date DESC
         LIMIT 1) AS qscore,
    round(
        CASE
            WHEN sum("cdata".impr) = 0 THEN 0::numeric
            ELSE sum("cdata".clicks)::numeric / sum("cdata".impr)::numeric
        END, 3) AS ctr,
    round(
        CASE
            WHEN sum("cdata".clicks) = 0 THEN 0::numeric
            ELSE sum("cdata".cost) / sum("cdata".clicks)::numeric
        END, 3) AS cpc,
    round(
        CASE
            WHEN sum("cdata".convcl) = 0::numeric THEN 0::numeric
            ELSE sum("cdata".cost) / sum("cdata".convcl)
        END, 3) AS cpa,
    round(
        CASE
            WHEN sum("cdata".impr) = 0 THEN 0::numeric
            ELSE sum("cdata".impr::numeric * "cdata".avgpos) / sum("cdata".impr)::numeric
        END, 2) AS avgpos,
    max("cdata".date) AS date
   FROM sqpr "cdata"
     LEFT JOIN kpr kpr ON "cdata".kid = kpr.id AND kpr.date = (( SELECT max(kpr.date) AS max
           FROM kpr
          WHERE kpr.id = "cdata".kid))
  GROUP BY "cdata".kword, "cdata".kid, "cdata".acc_id, "cdata".adgstatus, "cdata".adgcid, "cdata".adgname, "cdata".adgid, "cdata".sterm, "cdata".mtype, "cdata".url
```

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT ON` but I'm afraid it won't be very efficient over a complex query:  `SELECT DISTINCT ON (q.some_id) q.* FROM (your-query) AS q ORDER BY q.some_id, q.date DESC ;`, where `some_id` is whatever defines resulting rows to be duplicates (two rows with same `some_id` should not appear in the result, only 1 with the latest `date`).

Comment: Well, the problem is we would like to group all other columns. The reason is it contains values which we would like to sum. So distinct isn't an option. Like I said we would like to group all rows, but because of the different url's we would like to just show one url, from the row with the latest date. And group all other columns...

Comment: @ErikvandeVen: ypercube was talking about `distinct on (...)`, not `distinct`.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood it. I'm testing right now! :)

Comment: Not working and reading the documentation it seems it's not what I need: `DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. [...] Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first. [...] The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s).` Cause I want all columns grouped and just get the max (latest) url. Not the first row of the set.

Comment: `select max("cdata".url) as url,` does exactly what I want. The only problem is it doesn't return the url from the record with the latest date... as expected :(

Comment: Getting the first row from each group when ordering by date desc is the same thing as getting the latest.  If it didn't work, please show what you did, and what happened when you did it.

Comment: @ErikvandeVen, are the "duplicate" data in the `cdata` table or are they produced by the join to `kpr`? It would help if you provided the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both these tables.

Comment: @ypercube, they both contain duplicated data. The tables contain report data which gets bigger each day.

Comment: Out of curioucity, how many rows does the cdata (`sqpr`) table have and how many rows does (or should) the query return?

Comment: it contains about 2,5 million rows and the query above needs to return about 500.000 rows

Answer (score 0):

Guess I have figured it out.

By first selecting the first url:

```
select min("cdata".url) as url
```

And then order the query by date:

```
order by date asc
```

It does return the right url and it combines the rest of the columns.

**EDIT:**
Above answer did not work as expected. This didn't either: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)

**EDIT 2:**
Alright, I ran several tests and this seems to go well:

```
last("cdata".url) AS url
```

in combination with the max(date). So if someone has a better solution, please let me know :)

**EDIT 3:**
Alright, I think I just fixed it. I just select the url by executing a subquery and select the right row by comparing all "group by" fields, guess this is the best solution to my problem:

`(SELECT url from sqpr as cd where"cd".kword = "cdata".kword and cd.kid="cdata".kid and cd.accid="cdata".accid and cd. adgstatus ="cdata". adgstatus and cd. adgcid ="cdata". adgcid and cd. adgname ="cdata". adgname and cd. adgid ="cdata". adgid and cd. sterm ="cdata". sterm and cd. mtype ="cdata". mtype ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1) AS url`

Comment: But `select min(url), max(date) from ... group by ...;` does not guarantee that the date and url will be from the same row.

Comment: You are right, it didn't work as expected. So I'll edit my answer,

Comment: What is the data type of `url`, in the end?

Comment: character varying

Comment: If all fields except url  are equal between two rows after GROUP BY, including the `max(date)`, then `last(url)` is still a random pick. You didn't define the rule to discriminate what is the "good" and "bad" url in this case.

Comment: ow you mean that because of the max(date) all rows will get the same date... In that case it is a random pick indeed. But I haven't got a better solution. I did 5 checks, all rows returned the right url, so I thought it would be ok.

Comment: @Erik: the `last` you found discriminates among its inputs by keeping only the last one. But the inputs are presented to it in an order that is not guaranteed by anything in SQL.  That's why this `last` is not built-in, contrary to max or min: it's not deterministic.

Comment: Alright, I'm reading a lot about window functions right now. Could you tell me or it's possible to execute my first query (check my first post), which returns double rows as a window function, so I could grab the latest url by ordering by ID and limit the rows to 1, and after that group all rows together and use that latest url? I'm just thinking